# In MVC what is the best method to manage exceptions or errors in the business?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

In MVC what is the best method to manage exceptions or errors in the business? I found several solutions but do not know which to choose.

**Solution 1**

```
public Person GetPersonById(string id)
{
    MyProject.Model.Person person = null;
    try
    {
        person = _personDataProvider.GetPersonById(id);
    }
    catch 
    { 
        // I use a try / catch to handle the exception and I return a null value
        // I don't like this solution but the idea is to handle excpetion in 
        // business to always return valid object to my MVC.
        person = null; 
    }
    return person;
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
public Person GetPersonById(string id)
{
    MyProject.Model.Person person = null;
    person = _personDataProvider.GetPersonById(id);
    // I do nothing. It to my MVC to handle exceptions
    return person;
}
```

**Solution 3**

```
public Person GetPersonById(string id, ref MyProject.Technical.Errors errors)
{
    MyProject.Model.Person person = null;
    try
    {
        person = _personDataProvider.GetPersonById(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        // I use a try / catch to handle the exception but I return a 
        // collection of errors (or status). this solution allow me to return 
        // several exception in case of form validation.
        person = null; 
        errors.Add(ex); 
    }
    return person;
}
```

**Solution 4**

```
// A better idea ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest you to think about Null Object Pattern. Instead of returning null, return an empty object so that you don't have to perform multiple if null checks. You should create an abstract Person class that has a static property like NullPerson which contains default values. If your DAL returns null, you would return NullPerson. You can find more information on [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Let the exceptions be handled at the application level. I would suggest to go with **Solution 2**. You could use try..catch blocks when you want to change the logic when some exception happens else simply leave it to the application infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

System errors should be caught as soon as possible, while each and every object consuming your class should implemented necessary code to catch possible errors. Catching system errors at the lowest level lets you decide what you plan to do:
- Return no value
- Throw a custom error
- Rethrow the system error

Inserting an abstraction layer between system error and your custom error is that you can introduce new error requiring different attention. I.E.: if the error is FileNotFoundException, you might want make a difference between a normal error (i.e.: the file is a daily report but the file asket represent a future report) or not (the file should exist)

I would prefer solution 3, even if in a first phase you simply rethrow a regular exception when needed.

Serge

Answer (score 0):

That depends upon your requirement.

1. IF you just want to know whether our process successfully executed or not then Process 2 is advisable.
2. IF you are willing to write some error logs then Process 3 is best choice.
3. If you don't want to go with complex method yet you want to handle exception and write logs of it, then Process 1 is advisable.

Regards,
Pavan.G